# Variable Argument Functions, with classes as arguments. C++

Tags: c++, function, class, arguments

How to create a **function that can pass a variable number of arguments that are pointers to objects of the same class**? It is desirable that it would be impossible to pass other data types. (Its quantity will be passed too)

There are no problems when working with standard types of variables, but no examples of such use could be found.

Wouldn't that be a bad way to use functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
class C
{
public:
    void DoSomething(int n, C* ptrs[]) {
        // do something with n number of pointers from ptrs array...
   }
};
```

```cpp
C c1, c2, c3, c4;
C* arr[] = {&c2, &c3, &c4};
c1.DoSomething(3, arr);
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
class C
{
public:
    template<size_t n>
    void DoSomething(C* (&ptrs)[n]) {
        // do something with n number of pointers from ptrs array...
   }
};
```

```cpp
C c1, c2, c3, c4;
C* arr[] = {&c2, &c3, &c4};
c1.DoSomething(arr);
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>

class C
{
public:
    void DoSomething(std::initializer_list<C*> ptrs) {
        // do something with ptrs...
   }
};
```

```cpp
C c1, c2, c3, c4;
c1.DoSomething({&c2, &c3, &c4});
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
class C
{
public:
    void DoSomething() {}

    template<typename ...Ts>
    void DoSomething(C* c, Ts... args) {
        // do something with c...
        DoSomething(args...);
    }
};
```

```cpp
C c1, c2, c3, c4;
c1.DoSomething(&c2, &c3, &c4);
```